# AngularJS ngStyle is not applying to my table element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This works, the style is applied whenever the power threshold is exceeded.

```
<td ng-repeat ="n in range (0,191)" title="SC{{n}} {{value.Data | split:' ':n}}dBm" ng-style="{{value.Data | split:' ':n}} > {{pwrThreshold}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
```

This one does not and the code is mostly identical. The only difference is the data source. I've been able to print the values in an HTML element so I know they are there. I've tried removing the class and still does not work.  I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.PortPower | number}}" ng-style="{{port1.PortPower}} > {{PORTPOWERTHRESHOLD}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.Channel0 | number}}" ng-style="{{port1.Channel0}} > {{CHANNELPOWERTHRESHOLD}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.Channel1 | number}}" ng-style="{{port1.Channel1}} > {{CHANNELPOWERTHRESHOLD}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.Channel2 | number}}" ng-style="{{port1.Channel2}} > {{CHANNELPOWERTHRESHOLD}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.Channel3 | number}}" ng-style="{{port1.Channel3}} > {{CHANNELPOWERTHRESHOLD}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the curly braces {{}} from the expression seems to have corrected my problem and it now works fine.

```
<td class="table2" title="{{port1.PortPower | number}}" ng-style="port1.PortPower > PORTPOWERTHRESHOLD*  && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
```

Strangely though, if I try to do the same thing with my original working code(pasted below), it no longer works.  Anyone know why it would behave this way?  Is it because of split filter?  Also this code gives a syntax error in the console for the expression even though it performs exactly as expected.

```
<td ng-repeat ="n in range (0,191)" title="SC{{n}} {{value.Data | split:' ':n}}dBm" ng-style="{{value.Data | split:' ':n}} > {{pwrThreshold}} && {'background-color':'red'}"></td>
```